# Create github site/custom page/multiple project

Tags: github, github-pages

How to host sub project/another webapp on GitHub pages in a single account. I mean more than one. For ex: By default it is username.github.io but how can I host multiple like username.github.io/site2,username.github.io/site3, username.github.io/site4

Answer (score 0):

https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Are you using "User Pages"? There is also "Project Pages" that can do exactly what you are looking for.

Say you have a repo `my_repo`, you can have a page with address `http(s)://username.github.io/my_repo`. Unlike User Pages repo(`username.github.io`), you may not want to use your master branch for Project Page. you have a couple more options - using only *docs* directory in your master branch, or use `gh-pages` branch.

[This link](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/a-guide-to-using-github-pages/start/new-project/project-page/) kindly guides how to use.